# jQuery tooltip to display multiple items

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I am trying to use available jQuery tooltip code to display multiple lines in a tooltip. All the tooltips I can see pull in just one title attribute.

I display an image on a page and when I hover over it I want to display the item's title, price and stock number.

I can add this to my shop's code and return all these in html, eg

```
<div class="image">
<a href="%mylink%" >
<img src="%myimage%" title="%mytitle%"/></a>
</div>

<div class="price">
<a href="%mylink%">%price%</a>
</div>

<div class="sku">
<a href="%mylink%">%SKU%</a>
</div>
```

I have it working using this tooltip on the title attribute:

http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/index.html

but can't see how to add multiple items. Here's the code I use:

```
<script>
$(function() {
// initialize tooltip
$(".image img[title]").tooltip({

   // tweak the position
   offset: [10, 2],

   // use the "slide" effect
   effect: 'slide'

// add dynamic plugin with optional configuration for bottom edge
}).dynamic({ bottom: { direction: 'down', bounce: true } });
});
</script>
```

Is it possible?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you want more than one tooltip, or more content in the one tooltip?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are wanting in regards to multiple items, maybe an example of an expected outcome?

Comment: you need a slightly different setup to use multiple elements within the tooltip.
Have a look at http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/any-html.htm

Comment: @Jeroen - I need one tooltip with Title, price and SKU. I'll also need to format these with CSS so they need to be separate.

Comment: I guess I could use the html code as shown in my link above but I would then need to hide the tooltip class. I notice they apply a display:none to it, that may work.

Comment: Yes that has worked, thanks for the replies.